# Kivy Layout height to adapt to child widgets's height

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I want to create a layout where I have something similar to a BoxLayout to give me the ability to create "rows" in my layout, and in each "row" I want to use something in the sorts of another BoxLayout to create "columns".

The columns don't need to be evenly distributed. For example, I want to create a BoxLayout with one column with a square image, and another occupying the rest of the available width.

See code and screenshot on my gist: https://gist.github.com/MichaelGradek/e5c50038b947352d9e79

I have the basic structure done in the code above, but in addition, **I want the BoxLayout's height to adapt to the height of the children.**

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use a BoxLayout, use a GridLayout with `height: self.minimum_height`, and set a manual size (`size_hint_y: None` and `height: some_number`) for each child widget.

Comment: Why do you need both height and size_hint?

Comment: @inclement, I think you also need to `size_hint_y: None` in the `GridLayout`, not only in the children

Comment: @zwep, because kivy honors `size_hint` over `size`, meaning everything related to direct pixels sizes (including `height` and `width`) will be ignored, unless the corresponding `size_hint` is set to `None`. Kivy was build responsive first, so size_hints are priorized.

Answer (score 4):

For me, using a GridLayout with height: self.minimum_height, and then setting a manual size (size_hint_y: None and height: some_number) for each child widget, resulted in widgets getting anchored to the bottom of root window. Couldn't really figure out why?

However, using a GridLayout with height: root.height, and then setting a manual size (size_hint_y: None and height: some_number) for each child widget resulted in correct top anchored widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some tricks I've figured out for setting `GridLayout` height based off children height, however, both require one child per row... so making columns does require adding an internal grid layout.

```
# kv file or string
<Resizing_GridLayout@GridLayout>:
    cols: 1
    row_force_default: True
    foo: [self.rows_minimum.update({i: x.height}) for i, x in enumerate(reversed(list(self.children)))]
```

Above could be added to either via Python code or static `kv` entries and in my project is at least behaving itself for resizing each row off the contained child widget.

```
# kv file or string for when above goes funky
<ResizingRow_GridLayout@GridLayout>:
    cols: 1
    height: sum([c.height for c in self.children])
```

And for completeness, an example of how to stitch both of'em togeather...

```
# ... assuming above have been set, bellow maybe within another layout
Resizing_GridLayout:
    ResizingRow_GridLayout:
        Label:
            height: 30
            text: 'Label One'
        TextInput:
            height: 30
            multiline: False
            write_tab: False
            hint_text: 'Insert one liner'
    ResizingRow_GridLayout:
        Label:
            height: 45
            text: 'Label two'
        Button:
            text: 'Button One'
            height: 60
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            height: 25
            Button:
                text: 'Button Two'
            Button:
                text: 'Button three'
```

---

### Updates

**[`modules/adaptive-grid-layout/__init__.py`](https://github.com/kivy-utilities/adaptive-grid-layout/blob/master/__init__.py)**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from collections import OrderedDict
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock


class Adaptive_GridLayout(GridLayout):
    """
    Adaptive height and row heights for grid layouts.

    Note this should not be used as a root layout and '_refresh_grids_y_dimension()' method should be used by
    children widgets that change height to update all attached instances of Adaptive_GridLayout (this layout).

    Copyright AGPL-3.0 2019 S0AndS0
    """

    def __init__(self, grow_cols = False, grow_rows = False, **kwargs):
        super(Adaptive_GridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.grow_cols = grow_cols
        self.grow_rows = grow_rows
        self.trigger_refresh_y_dimension = Clock.create_trigger(lambda _: self._refresh_grids_y_dimension(), 0)

    def _yield_tallest_of_each_row(self):
        """ Yields tallest child of each row within gridlayout. """
        current_tallest = None
        for i, c in enumerate(list(reversed(self.children))):
            if current_tallest is None:
                current_tallest = c

            if c.height > current_tallest.height:
                current_tallest = c

            ## Should work around grids without value for 'cols'
            if self.cols is None or self.cols is 0:
                yield current_tallest
                current_tallest = None
            ## Reached last item of current row... Fizzbuzz!
            elif ((i + 1) % self.cols == 0) is True:
                yield current_tallest
                current_tallest = None

    def _calc_child_padding_y(self, child):
        """ Returns total padding for a given child. """
        ## May be faster than asking permission with an if statement as most widgets seem to have padding
        try:
            child_padding = child.padding
        except AttributeError as e:
            child_padding = [0]

        len_child_padding = len(child_padding)
        if len_child_padding is 1:
            padding = child_padding[0] * 2
        elif len_child_padding is 2:
            padding = child_padding[1] * 2
        elif len_child_padding > 2:
            padding = child_padding[1] + child_padding[3]
        else:
            padding = 0

        return padding

    def _calc_min_height(self):
        """ Returns total height required to display tallest children of each row plus spacing between widgets. """
        min_height = 0
        for c in self._yield_tallest_of_each_row():
            min_height += c.height + self._calc_child_padding_y(child = c) + self.spacing[1]
        return min_height

    def _calc_rows_minimum(self):
        """ Returns ordered dictionary of how high each row should be to accommodate tallest children of each row. """
        rows_minimum = OrderedDict()
        for i, c in enumerate(self._yield_tallest_of_each_row()):
            rows_minimum.update({i: c.height + self._calc_child_padding_y(child = c)})
        return rows_minimum

    def _refresh_height(self):
        """ Resets 'self.height' using value returned by '_calc_min_height' method. """
        self.height = self._calc_min_height()

    def _refresh_rows_minimum(self):
        """ Resets 'self.rows_minimum' using value returned by '_calc_rows_minimum' method. """
        self.rows_minimum = self._calc_rows_minimum()

    def _refresh_grids_y_dimension(self):
        """ Updates 'height' and 'rows_minimum' first for spawn, then for self, and finally for any progenitors. """
        spawn = [x for x in self.walk(restrict = True) if hasattr(x, '_refresh_grids_y_dimension') and x is not self]
        for item in spawn:
            item._refresh_rows_minimum()
            item._refresh_height()

        self._refresh_rows_minimum()
        self._refresh_height()

        progenitors = [x for x in self.walk_reverse() if hasattr(x, '_refresh_grids_y_dimension') and x is not self]
        for progenitor in progenitors:
            progenitor._refresh_rows_minimum()
            progenitor._refresh_height()

    def on_children(self, instance, value):
        """ If 'grow_cols' or 'grow_rows' is True this will grow layout that way if needed instead of erroring out. """
        smax = self.get_max_widgets()
        widget_count = len(value)
        if smax and widget_count > smax:
            increase_by = widget_count - smax
            if self.grow_cols is True:
                self.cols += increase_by
            elif self.grow_rows is True:
                self.rows += increase_by
        super(Adaptive_GridLayout, self).on_children(instance, value)

    def on_parent(self, instance, value):
        """ Some adjustments maybe needed to get top row behaving on all platforms. """
        self.trigger_refresh_y_dimension()
```

Above is from a project that I've published, it's pulled from a much larger project and may or may not suite those that want a bit more logic on the Python side for updating dimensions. Check the `ReadMe` file for tips on installation within another project.

Comment: This does not seem to work if `ResizingRow_GridLayout` contains a widget that dynamically adds children to itself.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!... it's been a while for Kivi but I've a feeling that moving the `foo:` _one-liner_ into a class method of `Resizing_GridLayout`, then one might be able to `height: self.calc_height()`

Comment: This [didn't seem to help](https://pastebin.com/djS4jSk8). I'm probably misunderstanding what you mean. And I need to understand what `self.calc_height()` is before trying this on a more [complex case](https://pastebin.com/NX2Maxq0) in which the dynamically added child can change size.

Comment: @FergusWyrm Yeah, I could have been a bit more explicit... check the updates and link to the GitHub project that I've published for tracking this feature... Line `24` within your PasteBin link is one problem spot, `foo: stuff` within a Kivy `kv` file is a _hackish_ way of running something at instantiation, though line `71` might do a similar thing, really such stuff should be a _`def`inition_ (AKA class method/function)... meaning that one would `def calc_height(self):...` so that other methods may call `self.cal_height()` or _`instance.cal_height()`_

Comment: Wow, that's a lot work you did. I did [try it out](https://pastebin.com/h7gk4yNp). Instead of a widget dynamically adding children to itself, a derived class of [your](https://github.com/kivy-utilities/adaptive-grid-layout) `Adaptive_GridLayout` is being used. This layout stretches child widgets to fit in absence of `size_hint_y: None`. That's good. But when children do have a fixed height, `Adaptive_GridLayout` doesn't shrink or stretch to match that height. Even calling `trigger_refresh_y_dimension()` doesn't seem to fix this. Also [foo has problem as a method](https://pastebin.com/wAxyfMfK)

Comment: @FergusWyrm thanks... If I remember correctly I had to use the `Adaptive_GridLayout` as a _base_ for a lot of other layout classes, however, doing so requires remembering the extra parameters during initialization (`grow_cols` and/or `grow_rows`) or overwriting'em after initialization; which could also be set within the `.kv` file... Additionally children of children as well as text fields require a bit of extra attention... I'll push a small project in a bit that utilizes the `Resizing_GridLayout` class, so that there's a bit more context for those that want this feature.

Comment: foo works fine. I got foo to behave the same in builder and as a class function. And I did make [a small project](https://pastebin.com/2BhdteYe) that shows this strange behavior more reliably. Try disabling `self.trigger_refresh_y_dimension()` in `ResizingFrame` and paste lorum ipsum into the stretching label. This should call `self.trigger_refresh_y_dimension()` from a child as intended. Then you can see it just moves the label down slightly.

Comment: You're getting close to something fully functional @FergusWyrm... I've pushed another bit of code [`kivy-utilities/adaptive-text-input`](https://github.com/kivy-utilities/adaptive-text-input) that shows various _hooks_ for updating text inputs... It'll still be a bit before I push a project utilizing both, though I've a feeling you'll have something operational shortly with the code so far shared... One other hint I can share in the mean time; I found the source code for Kivy to very instructional.

Comment: Oh my. Thanks for the new class. But I'm happy with my `StretchingLabel` class. It changes sizes just how I need it too. But in [the code earlier](https://pastebin.com/2BhdteYe), I couldn't get `Adaptive_GridLayout` to shrink or expand to match the size of the StretchingLabel (or even a regular label).

Comment: Most welcome @FergusWyrm, it'll be there if/when needed... It _looks_ like you're using `ResizingFrame` correctly, may be there's a bug within the code that I shared... It'll take me a bit to catch back up with my past-self, GitHub will be where updates and new code will appear first, but I'll do my best to update here as well when I've got it re-sorted... In the meantime it might be a good idea to post a new question here or on the Code Review sub-domain as there's likely many clever minds that might be faster than I at pointing where something is amiss.

Comment: @FergusWyrm does adding `size_hint: none` or `size_hint = None` to each of the children elements as well as any _`Adaptive_GridLayout`s_ resolve the odd sizing issues?... if that works thanks should be to [@inclement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32528681/2632107)  and @toto_tico too for already explaining why.

Comment: I found a few problems with `Adaptive_GridLayout`. #1: the height was not changing despite claiming so in `_refresh_height()`. #2 The `padding` is added to any size estimates incorrectly. Padding is part of height and shouldn't be taken into account. Adding `self.size_hint_y = None` to `__init__()` fixed problem #1. I'll have to find exactly where sizes are being miscalculated to fix problem #2. I suspect one more undiagnosed problem remains in relation to `rows_minimum`.

Comment: The `size_hint_y` should be set to `None` for **any** element that you wish to have the height honored, and while ya might be right about padding being miscalculated, but for padding to be included within height or width properties doesn't make sense... I too thought that `rows_minimum` was causing issues, but couldn't find anything amiss, especially after setting each inner element with `size_hint_y: None`. Thank you @FergusWyrm for the code review! Please issue a pull request if ya fix anything; I'll likely be making more pushes in a bit as I've another use cases I'm writing up.

Comment: I got it to work. The problem was `foo`. I got rid of it, and I didn't event need to set `size_hint_y` to `None` for the child widgets. [This](https://pastebin.com/j7Y1myVP) is a working example with widgets of static size. [This](https://pastebin.com/gaQpK9hk) is a working example with a label that dynamically changes size. And [this](https://pastebin.com/cKDzgwSp) is the version of `adaptive_grid_layout` I got to work (I used that as the filename since python doesn't like - in module names). Sorry, I'm not good at github yet. This took me a month to solve. Yay, and thanks for the help.

Comment: Excellent, @FergusWyrm you rock! I'll spend a bit of time perusing your edits... The [Kivyframework](https://twitter.com/kivyframework/status/1160240927874719744?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) also notified me that `size: self.minimum_size` might be equivalent to _some_ of the calculations that `Adaptive_GridLayout` is doing for total size... Indeed I had a :facepunch: moment with file names and hyphens too, sorry for that. And no worries on Git proficiency I too am still learning new ways to make mistakes ;-)

Comment: Both `rows` and `cols` need to be assigned for `grow_` features to be tripped. The changes to `_calc_min_height` cause some strangeness when adding elements after application start, but `_calc_rows_minimum` changes seem to work great... Hint for future debugging; `**kwargs` assigns extra parameters to a dictionary, meaning that `self.debug = kwargs.get('debug', False)` may be used to extend what a class understands, and strings have a `.format()` method, eg. `print("{}._yield_tallest_of_each_row():".format(self))`, which has some other fancy things that it can do too.