# Kivy: Can't change height of nested GridLayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, height

I have a simple user interface in kivy that consists of several gridlayouts inside of one large gridlayout. 
**The Code** 
This is the kv code for the interface

```
Builder.load_string('''
<GreyLabel>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 30
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .7, .7, .7, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<ContainerBox>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        row_force_default: True
        foo: [self.rows_minimum.update({i: x.height}) for i, x in enumerate(reversed(list(self.children)))]
        ResizingFrame:
            id: Row1
            cols: 1
            GreyLabel:
                text: "Something goes here"
        GridLayout:
            id: Row2
            cols: 1
            Label:
                height: 30
                text: 'Label One'
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: .4, .4, .4, 1
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
            TextInput:
                height: 30
                multiline: False
                write_tab: False
                hint_text: 'Insert one liner'

        GridLayout:
            id: Row3
            cols: 1
            Label:
                height: 45
                text: 'Label two'
            Button:
                text: 'Button One'
                height: 60
            GridLayout:
                rows: 1
                height: 25
                Button:
                    text: 'Button Two'
                Button:
                    text: 'Button three'
''')
```

Notice the `ResizingFrame` item. This is a `GridLayout` class with the following code

```
class ResizingFrame(GridLayout):
    c_value = StringProperty('SomeThing goes here')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ResizingFrame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.adjustHeight(), 1)

    def adjustHeight(self):
        print("ResizingFrame.adjustHeight() before:", self.height)
        self.height = 40
        print("ResizingFrame.adjustHeight() after:", self.height)
```

You can find the entire code [here](https://pastebin.com/GE1qJBng).

**The Goal** 
I want to be able to change the height of `ResizingFrame`.
The interface starts out looking like this:
[image]

After 1 second, it should look like this:
[image]
But it's not doing that.

Whenever `adjustHeight()` runs, it says: 
ResizingFrame.adjustHeight() before: 100 
ResizingFrame.adjustHeight() after: 40

But this height change never actually happens for some reason. I simply can't change the height of `ResizingFrame`. Why is this happening? And how can I fix it?

**Note** 
This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518975/kivy-layout-height-to-adapt-to-child-widgetss-height).

I suspect the problem has something to do with the line: 
`foo: [self.rows_minimum.update({i: x.height}) for i, x in enumerate(reversed(list(self.children)))]` 
This should set the minimum height of the rows to the height of their children. But as you can see in screenshot 1, that's not happening. It just sets the minimum height to 100 and I can't change the height after that. I can't even increase the height above 100. It's just stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you can't change the size of the `ResizingFrame`, is that its `size_hint` takes preference over any size changes. So, modifying your `adjustHeight` method to:

```
def adjustHeight(self):
    print("ResizingFrame.adjustHeight() before:", self.height)
    self.size_hint_y = None
    self.height = 40
    print("ResizingFrame.adjustHeight() after:", self.height)
```

will allow the `height` change to take effect.

Note that without setting `size_hint_y` to `None`, the you are changing the `height` attribute, and that changed value is printed. But once your `adjustHeight` method completes, then the `ResizingFrame` height is recalculated and changed back to 100. You can see this by calling your original `adjustHeight` method more than once (the before `height` will always be bck to 100).

Comment: One thing to note is that in production `size_hint_y` may be set within a `.kv` file or during initialization, _`Label(size_hint_y = None)`_, and **each** element that one want's to control the height of will require setting `size_hint_y` to `None`